# I want to save file name as 1.jpg 2.jpg... 10.jpg

Tags: php

my problem is when I save image from line bot messenger they see each event and then work so I count number of file in directory(where I save image) and I want image name as 
1.jpg 
2.jpg 
3.jpg

```
if($typeMessage=='image'){ 
$responseMedia = $bot->getMessageContent($idMessage);
$dataBinary = $responseMedia->getRawBody();
$files = scandir($botDataUserFolder);
$num_files = count($files)-2;
$filenamesave = $num_files.'.'.jpg;
file_put_contents($fileFullSavePath,$dataBinary);
}
```

please let me know what wrong with this code? I still save image as 0.jpg or 1.jpg and they overwrite on the old file

Comment: try to use `$num_files = count($files) - 1; $filenamesave = $num_files.'.jpg';`

Comment: they show (noname).jpg and when I send 2nd number still overwrite on (noname).jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with you code that you make count($files)-2;

But in php function "scandir" you will always receive back additionally dots directories(current dir and parent dir).

By first call count($files)-2 will return 0 and you system will create 0.jpg

Try this code, it will automatically skip dots using FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS:

```
$save_path = "/tmp/dir_to_save";

$filesystem_iterator = new FilesystemIterator($save_path, 
FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$number_of_files = iterator_count($filesystem_iterator);

$filename_save = ($number_of_files + 1) . '.jpg';
file_put_contents($save_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename_save, "binary file data");
```

You will need to adapt it a little bit for you method, but it works correctly.

Comment: I try this one but they not save my image